# I have a raised button in Flutter that is overflown

Tags: flutter, containers, flutter-layout, card

I have a card and a container. Inside the card, I have a container and the conatiner has rows and columns. On the last column, I have a button that is overflown from the card.

Please check the image, I have too much logic in the code, that is why I am unable to share my complete code. That will be too hard for anyone to understand.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Spacer(),
 Container(

                        child: RaisedButton(

                          color: MyColors.primaryColor,
                          child: subonoff(subcatextraproduct[index]) && visbutton ? Text("   Get Once   ",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 10)) : Text("+ Add to Cart",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 10)),
                          onPressed: (){
                            subtotal=subtotal+subcatextraproduct[index].price.round();
                            grandtotal=subtotal+deliverycharges;
                            setState(() {
                              //change="Once";
                              // print("sum setstate");
                              // sum++;
                              myfunc();
                              //this.widget.callback(sum);

                            });
                            makefalsbutton(subcatextraproduct[index].id);
                            maketruecountr(subcatextraproduct[index].id);
                            totalcsetone(subcatextraproduct[index].id);
                          //  print("i am in add");
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Container` without any attributes but child and DO NOT use functions to make widgets

As for your question – try to wrap your button into `Expanded`

I'd recommend you to read this article https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Try this code:

```dart
class ProductRow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Image.network(
              'https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYOjL.png',
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Yougurt'),
                Text('1 kg'),
                Text('9% OFF'),
                Text('RS 110.0'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            label: const Text('Add to cart'),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried to replace my container with Expanded i got an another error 'RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.'

Comment: Check out original answer

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions:

1. Remove container
2. If you can’t remove container, replace it with `Flexible` widget. Set `fit: FlexFit.loose`

Comment: hi thanks for help but i am getting same error with same pixels overflown

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RaisedButton(
      onPressed: ...,
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Text(
          condition ? "Get Once" : "Add to cart",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Or

```
[
 Spacer(),
 Flexible(child: RaisedButton()),
 ...
]
```